# Container in docker is getting started but couldnt be found in "docker ps" command

Tags: docker, jenkins, ssh, centos, containers

I have created a 2 containers in docker. However, one of them is visible and other is not.
Context:
I have created 1 container by downloading the docker jenkins image file and that is up and running and can be seen using docker ps command.

Then, I have tried to create an Image file to be consumed by the second container.
The script I have used in VI to create image file:

```
FROM centos

RUN yum -y install openssh-server

RUN yum install -y passwd

RUN useradd remote_user && \
    echo "1234" | passwd remote_user --stdin &&  \
    mkdir /home/remote_user/.ssh && \
    chmod 700 /home/remote_user/.ssh

COPY remote-key.pub /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN chown remote_user:remote_user -R /home/remote_user/.ssh/ && \
    chmod 600 /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys

CMD /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

The script ran successfully as "docker-compose build" has successfully build the image from the script.

Once it was successfully built, I tried to start the it using:

```
[jenkins@localhost jenkins-data]$ docker-compose up -d
jenkins is up-to-date
Starting remote-host ... done
```

Post this, when i am doing :

```
[jenkins@localhost jenkins-data]$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
5c1ee0507091        jenkins/jenkins     "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   5 days ago          Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 50000/tcp   jenkins
```

Its only showing me one container running while the remote-host container is not visible.
Any way to ensure if the remote-host container is actually running or is there any issue?

New to docker and jenkins, any lead is highly appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Try `docker ps -a`

Comment: @Paolo I just tried this and found the following result:
3bd1095f86f5        jenkins/jenkins     "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   13 seconds ago      Up 10 seconds                 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 50000/tcp   jenkins
10a430e21300        remote-host         "/bin/sh -c '/usr/sb…"   13 seconds ago      Exited (1) 11 seconds ago                                         remote-host
7a9e9a154079        200b7c7edd35        "/bin/sh -c /usr/sbi…"   26 minutes ago      Exited (127) 26 minutes ago

Comment: Basically, the remote-host is getting exited somehow and thats why maybe its not showing in docker ps. Any reason as to why its getting exited automatically?

Answer (score 0):

`docker ps` only shows *running* containers.

Using `docker ps -a` you see both running and *stopped* containers.

See [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/) about `ps`.

Probably the `remote-host` container is not running any more?

Comment: Yes, its getting exited automatically, can you pls help determine the reason? and how we can prevent it from automatic shutdown?

Comment: @Annu How does your `remote-host` Dockerfile/docker-compose service look like?

Comment: The docker-compose.yml looks like this:   version: '3'
services:
  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: jenkins/jenkins
    ports:
      -  "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      -  $PWD/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
    networks:
      -  net
  remote_host:
     container_name: remote-host
     image: remote-host
     build:
       context: centos7
     networks:
       - net
networks:
  net:

Answer (score 0):

Container stopped because of the main process which launched by the CMD command detached and become daemon

the main process should be attached to the terminal so you have to remove `-D` from CMD command `CMD /usr/sbin/sshd -D` or you can follow [this approach](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/)

> run sshd in detached mode and use while sleep to keep the container
> running

Comment: Removing -D dint helped, its still getting exited and can only be see using docker ps -a